# CodeWars kata Fusc function running too long, but very fast locally

Tags: c#, performance, time-limit-exceeded

I have a solution to [this CodeWars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-fusc-function-part-2) that's being rejected as "too slow".

Basically, write `public static BigInteger Fusc(BigInteger n)` given:

> 1. fusc(0) = 0
> 2. fusc(1) = 1
> 3. fusc(2 * n) = fusc(n)
> 4. fusc(2 * n + 1) = fusc(n) + fusc(n + 1)

-- [CodeWars description](https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-fusc-function-part-1) (from part 1, which is formatted slightly nicer IMO)

I have the class below. `FuscInner` is a literal, naïve implementation, to offer a "known good" answer if needed; it's slow, but that's fine. The trouble that I'm running into is that `FuscInnerTest` runs against my test driver in a quarter second, but times out on CodeWars.

While I'm open to any suggestionst for cleaning up `FuscInnerTest` or `MediumInt`, my primary goal is to ascertain why it's running so poorly when I submit to CodeWars (of course, I don't know how many test cases it runs...).

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

public class FuscSolution {
    public static BigInteger Fusc(BigInteger n) {
        //var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var answer = FuscInnerTest(n);
        //timer.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine($"{n} {answer} : {timer.Elapsed}");
        //timer.Restart();
        //answer = FuscInner(n);
        //timer.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine($"{n} {answer} : {timer.Elapsed}");
        return answer;
    }

    private static BigInteger FuscInner(BigInteger n) {
        if (n == BigInteger.Zero) {
            return BigInteger.Zero;
        }
        if (n == BigInteger.One) {
            return BigInteger.One;
        }

        if (n % 2 == BigInteger.Zero) {
            return FuscInner(n / 2);
        }
        var half = n / 2;
        return FuscInner(half) + FuscInner(half + 1);
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<BigInteger, BigInteger> _dict = new Dictionary<BigInteger, BigInteger> {
        { BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.Zero },
        { BigInteger.One, BigInteger.One },
        { new BigInteger(3), new BigInteger(2) },
        { new BigInteger(5), new BigInteger(3) },
    };

    private static BigInteger FuscInnerTest(BigInteger n) {
        // note: making this a Dictionary<BigInteger, BigInteger> worked quickly locally, too
        // the "MediumInt" is an attempt to reduce the number of BigInteger allocations, since
        // they're immutable
        var queue = new Dictionary<BigInteger, MediumInt> {
            { n, new MediumInt(1) },
        };

        BigInteger answer = BigInteger.Zero;

        while (queue.Any()) {
            var current = queue.Keys.Max();
            if (_dict.ContainsKey(current)) {
                answer += _dict[current] * queue[current].ToBigInt();
                queue.Remove(current);
            } else {
                Dequeue(current);
                var half = current / 2;
                Enqueue(half, current);
                if (!current.IsEven) {
                    Enqueue(half + 1, current);
                }
                queue.Remove(current);
            }
        }

        return answer;

        void Dequeue(BigInteger toRemove) {
            if (queue.ContainsKey(toRemove)) {
                if (queue[toRemove].IsPositive()) {
                    queue[toRemove].Decriment();
                } else {
                    queue.Remove(toRemove);
                }
            }
        }

        void Enqueue(BigInteger toAdd, BigInteger parent) {
            if (queue.ContainsKey(toAdd)) {
                queue[toAdd].Incriment();
            } else {
                queue[toAdd] = new MediumInt(1);
            }
            if (parent != null) {
                if (queue.ContainsKey(parent)) {
                    queue[toAdd].Add(queue[parent]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MediumInt {
        private const int max = 2_000_000;
        private const int min = -2_000_000;

        private BigInteger big = BigInteger.Zero;
        private int current = 0;

        public MediumInt(int initialValue) {
            current = initialValue;
            Normalize();
        }

        public bool IsZero() {
            return big == BigInteger.Zero && current == 0;
        }

        public bool IsPositive() {
            if (IsZero()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (current == 0 && big <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (big == BigInteger.Zero && current <= 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (big == BigInteger.Zero) {
                return current > 0;
            }

            if (big > BigInteger.Zero && big > Math.Abs(current)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (big < BigInteger.Zero && big < Math.Abs(current)) {
                return true;
            }
            throw new Exception("IsPositive unknown state");
        }

        public void Incriment() {
            ++current;
            Normalize();
        }

        public void Decriment() {
            --current;
            Normalize();
        }

        public void Add(MediumInt value) {
            current += value.current;
            big += value.big;
            Normalize();
        }

        public BigInteger ToBigInt() {
            return big + current; ;
        }

        private void Normalize() {
            if (current > max || current < min) {
                big += current;
                current = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Driver code:

```c#
Assert.AreEqual(BigInteger.Zero, FuscSolution.Fusc(BigInteger.Zero));
Assert.AreEqual(BigInteger.One, FuscSolution.Fusc(BigInteger.One));
Assert.AreEqual(BigInteger.One, FuscSolution.Fusc(new BigInteger(4)));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(2), FuscSolution.Fusc(new BigInteger(3)));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(3), FuscSolution.Fusc(new BigInteger(10)));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(3), FuscSolution.Fusc(5));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(3), FuscSolution.Fusc(20));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(8), FuscSolution.Fusc(21));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(53), FuscSolution.Fusc(9007199254740991L));

// You need to pass these tests very quickly
BigInteger twoPThous = BigInteger.Pow(2, 1000);
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(1001), FuscSolution.Fusc(twoPThous + BigInteger.One));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(1000), FuscSolution.Fusc(twoPThous - BigInteger.One));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(2996), FuscSolution.Fusc(twoPThous + 5));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(7973), FuscSolution.Fusc(twoPThous + 21));
Assert.AreEqual(new BigInteger(50245), FuscSolution.Fusc(twoPThous + 9007199254740991L));
var e = BigInteger.Parse("40441312560834288620677930197198699407914760287917495887121626854370117030034851815445037809554113527157810884542426113562558179684997500659084090344407986124994461497183");
var a = BigInteger.Parse("4496047232746033439866332574607641115185289828815659836877207557974698638551430698226403383854431074455323285812344476437334109742500243442945967768558521790671067401423809250553312923996658420643391496408098163895264498830090255970293513331630261702288646149000136895514918279039816543329290294321200");
Assert.AreEqual(e, FuscSolution.Fusc(a));
```

Comment: First i can see that you check if it 0 or 1 each iteration before calculations. Maybe reorder checks e.g. 3-4-1-2? Also you can use [`DivRem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem?view=netframework-4.8) because you need both at once, also `IsEven`, `IsZero`, `IsOne` properties may help.

Comment: The link you provided suggests using tail recursion, which C# does not support natively.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to my question of "why is it timing out on submission" turns out to be that it's running 10k super-large values. I suspect that this approach is a dead end

Some stats that may be of interest about the last test case:

- runs through the `while` loop 1992 times
- performs work in `Normalize` 331 times across all `MediumInt` instances
- bumping `MediumInt`'s scratch values up to `long`s and setting the thresholds to +-4_500_000_000_000_000_000 only drops that count to 286

My initial reading of the problem (and some poking to get a couple of random known-correct super-large expected/actual pairs) suggested that the test included only a few of those super-large values, to prevent the naïve recursive solution from working. But, looping over that last test case 10k times runs in just over 28 seconds (twice the 12-second limit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your rationale for introducing the `MediumInt` class. You have written:

```
// the "MediumInt" is an attempt to reduce the number of BigInteger allocations, since
// they're immutable
```

The `System.Numerics.BigInteger` is a struct so there's no heap allocation anyway. I haven't profiled your code so it may be faster but maybe not for the reason you think. Sometimes it can be helpful to have a wrapper to avoid having to key into a dictionary twice:

```
public class Counter
{
    public BigInteger Current { get; set; }
}


// One example of using it:
if (!someDictionary.TryGetValue(someKey, out Counter c)
{
    someDictionary[someKey] = c = new Counter();
}
c.Current++;
```

This also shows something else you want to be doing, using [TryGetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue). If you're looking up in your dictionary as much as I expect, it will yield a good gain. Applying it to your Enqueue local function, using the simplified `Counter` class and fixing the brace style:

```
void Enqueue(BigInteger toAdd, BigInteger parent)
{
    if (queue.TryGetValue(toAdd, out var counter))
    {
        counter.Value++;
    } 
    else
    {
        queue[toAdd] = counter = new Counter { Value = new BigInteger(1) };
    }
    if (parent != null && queue.TryGetValue(parent, out var parentCounter)) 
    {
        counter.Value += parentCounter.Value;
    }
}
```

All of this comes with the caveat that I have neither compiled nor run any of it. I can give it a test tomorrow and update if you don't try it before then. Have you attempted to work through the tail call recursion as the question suggests?

Comment: While BigInts are structs, my understanding is that they're immutable; thus, small operations (like incrementing/decrementing, like in Enqueue and Dequeue) get expensive because they instantiate a new instance. ... I've started looking at the tail call recursion, but I don't have enough math readily at hand to do it, alas.